# What are job regulations for early career researchers in US compared to Germany?

Tags: job

In Germany, the job of a scientist for the public sector is regulated in a way that

- on time limited contracts which are the general case you can work [at most 6 years before achieving your PhD and at most 6 after it](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86864/why-are-most-universities-reluctant-to-offer-open-ended-contracts-to-research-fu/86871#86871)  (*[Wissenschaftszeitvertragsgesetz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wissenschaftszeitvertragsgesetz)*) and then only on permanent contracts (extremely rare) or under very special circumstances;
- your payment follows a fixed payment [agreement framework](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84933/whats-the-difference-between-german-tv-l-and-tv%C3%B6d-pay-scales/84934#84934) ([*TVÖD*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarifvertrag_f%C3%BCr_den_%C3%B6ffentlichen_Dienst)).

Are there comparable regulations in US?

Comment: The first point refers to fixed term contracts, mainly postdocs. You can of course continue to work as a professor (if you get the position).

Comment: Your first bullet is an oversimplification. First, you can work for six years before and another six year after PhD. Then, this only applies to time limited contracts. There is the possibility to work  on "unlimited" contracts either as professor or with another position (although these are rare). Moreover, you can over the six years after PhD on project funding.

Comment: Please change the title of your question to reflect that it only concerns with regulations for early career researchers, not all academia. There is also a set of regulations concerning professors (that they are not allowed to strike, maximum employment age, etc.), which your question doesn't concern with.

Comment: In broad terms the answer to this question is NO. In the US there are nothing like the regulations regarding academic employment that exist in most European countries. One can work multiple temporary jobs of varying duration. Conditions of employment vary greatly from institution to institution, and modalities are flexible. There is no uniform public sector legislation because there is no academic "system" at the federal level, education being a state competency. Specific contracts/grants might have limits (e.g. an NSF postdoc), but those apply only to to those contracts/grants themselves.

Comment: @DanFox There is no academic system at the federal level either in Germany (disregarding some federal research institutes here). However, employment laws are federal.